# Additional examples of Appealing to Bat Kol?

Tags: halacha-theory, emes-truth-honesty

Besides Tanuro Shel Akhnai story (B"M 59b) where R' Eliezer appealed to the Heavenly voice to prove him right, what are additional examples of Chachamim appealing to the Bat Kol to prove their truthfulness?

Comment: See the responsa Min HaShamayim [and RR Margolios’ intro. to his edition]. * *grabs popcorn, proceeds to watch heads explode* *

Comment: @Oliver Is that a real Sefer? Do you have an online link?

Comment: @DonielF [It is](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/21989), can’t find Margolios’ edition online.

Comment: You're only asking about cases where they **appealed** to the _bas kol_, right? So, excluding (for example) "נחלקו ב״ש וב״ה הללו אומרים הלכה כמותנו והללו אומרים הלכה כמותנו יצאה בת קול ואמרה אלו ואלו דברי אלהים חיים הן והלכה כב״ה"?